# How to get the vertex that I clicked on OCC widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencascade

I use OCC with python to visualize .igs and .stl format. In .stl file I have a mesh on my model and I want to know what vertex on this mesh was clicked. At least to get some kind of id. I see that the model that I choose automatically highlights without any settings, so I guess there is a way to do this. But I couldn’t find any information about it. 
[image: Model with mesh]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, found it. In case someone else will need it:

```
 display = self.occWidget._display
 display.SetSelectionModeVertex() # This is the required function
 display.register_select_callback(recognize_clicked)
```

where recognize_clicked is

```
def recognize_clicked(shp, *kwargs):
""" This is the function called every time
a face is clicked in the 3d view
"""
for shape in shp:
    print("Face selected: ", shape)
```

Face selection - `SetSelectionModeFace()`

Vertex selection - `SetSelectionModeVertex()`

Edge selection - `SetSelectionModeEdge()`

Shape selection - `SetSelectionModeShape()`

Neutral (default) selection - `SetSelectionModeNeutral()`

That is all the modes that I've found in other examples. Please, if you find more, write in a comment that resource.

Comment: Hi. What are the imports that I need to run your code? Also, would you mind sharing how you implemented recognize_clicked? I'm not sure how to write a recognize_clicked function with SetSelectionModeShape().

Comment: @JamesLee sorry, I just checked the repository, and there is no such code. I probably changed it before or after committing there =( I remember how painful it was to achieve something with 3d models, but everything I wanted I implemented. So just keep searching!